# Create Dynamic Object Request In Retrofit

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit

How can I create Dynamic Object for retrofit request. e.g
example request 1:

```
 "answer" :     {
        "Aggravating factor" :         {
            "value_dropdown" : "None"
        },
        "Associated factors" :         {
            "value" : "1"
        }
}
```

example request 2:

```
 "answer" :     {
            "Intensity :         {
                "value_dropdown" : "Major"
            },
            "Duration" :         {
                "value" : "5"
            }
    }
```

so every time The request model is changing,
I have all these parameternames and values that i collect from an answer form 
 filled by end user, then how can is use it to create request model with dynamic values i.e. "answer" : {{"parameter name" : "value"}}.

My effort:
a static model with it's serialization output:

```
public class SampleModel {


    @SerializedName("answer")
    public ArrayList<QuestionAnswers> answer;

    public SampleModel() {
        answer = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    public static class QuestionAnswers {
        public String question_title;
        public List<KeyValuePaire> questions;

        public QuestionAnswers() {
            questions = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    public static class KeyValuePaire {
        public String _type;
        public String _value;
    }

}
```

this model request prints below log :

```
{
  "answer": [
    {
      "question_title": "Aggravating factor",
      "questions": [
        {
          "_type": "value_dropdown",
          "_value": "None"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: We can use a Generic Object here. Did you try?

Comment: @TheAnkush Solved it using TreeMap Where key of the TreeMap is then treated as parametername and the value as value. Thank you for your Response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it using TreeMap Where key of the TreeMap is then treated as parameter name and the value as value.

```
public class RequestSelectedAnswers {

    @SerializedName("answer")
    TreeMap answers;

    public RequestSelectedAnswers() {
        answers = new TreeMap();
    }

    public TreeMap getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(TreeMap answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }

}
```

And Use It Like:

```
RequestSelectedAnswers request = new RequestSelectedAnswers();       
request.getAnswers().put("Intensity", someArrayOrAnotherMap);
```